# What is the mean of the random variable $\min\{X_1,X_2\}$ and $\max\{X_1,X_2\}$, where each $X_i$ is distributed uniformly over $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability

So as stated on the title, what is the mean of the random variable $\min\{X_1,X_2\}$ and $\max\{X_1,X_2\}$, where each $X_i$ is distributed uniformly over $[0,1]$?

I know it's going to be $1/3$ and $2/3$ but I cannot derive it analytically.

Thank you in advance

Paul

Comment: Do you know the definition of the mean (a.k.a. the expectation) of a random variable?

Answer (score 1):

The function $\min(x,y)$ can be detected by considering the function $x-y$. When $x-y\ge 0$, we have $\min(x,y)=y$, and when $x-y<0$ we have $\min(x,y)=x$.

So it suffice to consider the value of $x-y$ on the unit square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. It is obvious that above the diagonal line, $x-y<0$, and below the diagonal line, $x-y\ge 0$. So to calculate the "mean" of $\min(x,y)$ it suffice to integrate $x$ on the upper half triangle and $y$ on the lower half triangle.

Now write integral along the upper half triangle as $$\int^{y}_{0}xdx\int^{1}_{0}dy=\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{2}y^{2}dy=\frac{1}{6}$$
The integral along the lower half triangle as 
$$\int^{x}_{0}ydy\int^{1}_{0}dx=\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{2}x^{2}dx=\frac{1}{6}$$

So the whole "mean" is the sum $\frac{1}{3}$. I am leaving the second result for you to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Two basic facts:

> (1) CDF are better suited than PDF when dealing with maxima and minima of independent random variables.
>
> (2) To compute expectations of nonnegative random variables, CDF can be used instead of PDF.

Let $Y=\min\{X_1,X_2\}$, then Fact 2 is based on the identity $E[Y]=\int\limits_0^\infty P[Y\geqslant y]\mathrm dy$ and Fact 1 is based on the fact that, for every $y\geqslant0$, $[Y\geqslant y]=[X_1\geqslant y]\cap[X_2\geqslant y]$.

In the case at hand, $P[Y\geqslant y]=P[X_1\geqslant y]\cdot P[X_2\geqslant y]=(1-y)^2$ for $0\leqslant y\leqslant1$ and $P[Y\geqslant y]=0$ for $y\geqslant1$. This yields
$$
E[Y]=\int_0^1(1-y)^2\mathrm dy=\left[\tfrac13z^3\right]_0^1=\tfrac13.
$$
Finally, let $Z=\max\{X_1,X_2\}$, then $Z=X_1+X_2-Y$ hence $E[Z]=2E[X_1]-E[Y]=\ldots$